# UnityC# OnStart во вложенном массиве по нулевому индексу очищаются объекты, остальное не тронуто

Tags: массивы, unity3d, switch

Есть следующая проблема: при нажатии Play в Unity мой вложенный массив очищает объекты в нулевом индексе, притом очищение происходит не как в Play режиме, так как оно не восстанавливается после выхода из режима Play.

Код написанный мной страшный, ибо я не знаю как правильно писать Generic классы.  Если будут предложения к исправлению, пожалуйста, я с удовольствием их приму.

Код выполняет несложную задачу. Идея :
Изменить объект или его состояние на другой объект или состояние. Допустим, если одно состояние требует множество изменений у одного объекта или цепочку объектов, то этот скрипт может это воспроизвести. Важно, чтобы не плодить код, я написал универсальный класс, который можно унаследовать и определить свои объекты для изменения их.

```
public abstract class Switcher<TSwitchData,TObject, TValue> : ComponentView where TSwitchData : SwitchData<TObject,TValue>
{
    [SerializeField] private int _state = 0;
    [SerializeField] private TSwitchData[] _objectList = null;
    public event System.Action<int> OnSwitchState;

    public void SetStateOverride(int state)
    {
        Switch(state);
    }
    public void Switch(int? state = null)
    {
        int index = -1;
        foreach (var item in _objectList)
        {
            index++;
            _state = state ?? _state;
            if (_state == item.SwitchList.Length || _state > item.SwitchList.Length || _state < 0)
            {
                _state = 0;
            }
            else if (item.SwitchList.Length == 0)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"{this} : Array : {index} is empty!!!");
                continue;
            }
            OnChange(item.TargetObject, item.SwitchList[_state], _state);
        }
        OnSwitchState?.Invoke(_state);
        _state++;
    }
    protected abstract void OnChange(TObject obj, TValue value, int state);
}
```

Его объект для пере использования :

```
[Serializable]
public class SwitchData<TObject, TValue>
{
    [SerializeField] private TObject _targetObject = default;
    [SerializeField] private TValue[] _switchList = default;
    public TObject TargetObject => _targetObject;
    public TValue[] SwitchList => _switchList;
}
```

И собственно пример использования :

```
[Serializable]
public class SpriteRendererSD : SwitchData<SpriteRenderer, Sprite> { }
public class SpriteRendererSwitcher : Switcher<SpriteRendererSD, SpriteRenderer, Sprite>
{
    protected override void OnChange(SpriteRenderer obj, Sprite value, int state)
    {
        obj.sprite = value;
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Переустановил объекты в сцене, заработало. Странно но я не ссылался никак на них.. Если будут ответы или помощь по правильности написания кода, буду рад))